# Not able to add limit in the GROUP_CONCAT(distinct(..))

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, distinct, group-concat, sql-limit

```
SELECT 
    quiz.id AS quizId,
    quiz.name AS quizName,
    GROUP_CONCAT(distinct(quiz_attempt.quiz_attempt_status)
        ORDER BY quiz_attempt.id DESC limit 1) AS quizAttemptStatus
FROM
    course
        LEFT JOIN
    quiz ON quiz.id = course.quiz
        LEFT JOIN
    quiz_attempt ON quiz_attempt.quiz = quiz.id
WHERE
    (course.id = 'courseId'
        AND quiz_attempt.user = 'userId' )
GROUP BY quiz.id , quiz_attempt.id
```

When I am adding limit inside GROUP_CONCAT(distinct(... )), it is not working and I want latest attempt for each quiz in the course. How to do it?

Comment: remove limit from your GROUP_CONCAT statement
`GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT (quiz_attempt.quiz_attempt_status) ORDER BY quiz_attempt.id DESC) AS quizAttemptStatus`

Comment: I want latest attempt status so, I need to add limit to it, is there any other way to get latest attempt details? After removing limit it gives all quizzes all attempt, which is not what I want.

Comment: then you need to try subquery instead of group_concat

Answer (score 0):

try using row-number and then only grabbing first row-number?

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    [PARTITION BY partition_expression, ... ]
    ORDER BY sort_expression [ASC | DESC], ...
)
```

also see more info here:
https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-window-functions/sql-server-row_number-function/

Comment: it is not working, as for each course there are many quizzes and each quiz has many attempts and I want only latest attempt for each quiz

Comment: if you can list the quizzes and their attempts then you can get the last or first pretty simple by using row_number and an ordering